# Telethon get channel participants without admin privilages

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I am using telethon to handle a client on a custom app. What I would like to do is show the list of people subscribed to a certain telegram channel. Here is the setup:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

api_id = 8045283
api_hash = 'ad63dec5ee12u8baca534620d5b3d725' #not real btw
client = TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash)
await client.start()
```

After this I have tried functions like `client.get_participants(channel)`, which returns the error:

```
ChatAdminRequiredError: Chat admin privileges are required to do that in the specified chat (for example, to send a message in a channel which is not yours), or invalid permissions used for the channel or group (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)
```

And also `await client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel=channel))`, which just doesn't have the required information.

I thought that this API was created exactly to create custom clients, but how is this possible if basic functionality cannot be implemented? Can anyone give a suggestion on how to achieve this? Maybe another way of getting such data?

Comment: If an official client does not provide the functionality, it is very likely because of an API limitation. No application can bypass the limits on Telegram's API.

Comment: @Lonami but Telegram is opensource, which means that they use the same API as any other app like Telegram X for example. And they both CAN show the list of group users. https://imgur.com/a/Z8sES83

Comment: The server is not open source. However, if Telegram X can do it, then Telethon can do it too. But it might be a different method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I have actually confused terminology here. Telegram does not show the participant of the channel even on the official app (if you are not an admin), however, for Groups the `get_participants` method works great

Comment: Still doesn't return all participants of a supergroup :(

Answer (score 2):

```
async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
        if  dialog.is_channel:
       
            print( dialog.entity.participants_count)
```

this is how you can get participants count without being an admin

Comment: what about get name of each participant instead of total count?